# Element to render itself on top of its parent's other element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am building a React application. The code structure is as follow:

```
<Div>
<Div style={{maxHeight:'60vh'}}>
   //Contains code for displaying a list item and each item has it's context menu that can be triggered from an icon click.
</Div>
<Div style={{maxHeight:'40vh'}}></Div>
</Div>
```

Div has a max height set on them. When user clicks on the icon, context menu gets displayed. The problem is, it gets display within the scrollbar, I wanted the context menu to be on top of the screen i.e. the menu should take the entire div to display the option instead of trying to render inside the first div itself.

The context menu component is present in first div itself.

Is there any CSS or other way to fix this?

***Current Behavior:***

[image]

***Expected Behavior:***
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I pulled out the context menu into a separate React component and when user clicks on the item (...), progamatically, I am handling the visibility if the content menu.

So my structure is now like this:

```
<Div>
<Div id="firstDiv" style={{maxHeight:'60vh'}}></Div>
<Div id="secondDiv" style={{maxHeight:'40vh'}}></Div>
<Div show="conditional rendering">
  // first Div menu options displayed in React-Bootstrap Toasts
</Div>
<Div show="conditional rendering">
 // second Div menu options displayed in React-Bootstrap Toasts
</Div>
</Div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to `margin`/`padding`. Try to give `maxHeight` in `%` (percentage). You have to give height of parent div.

```html
<div>
<div style={{maxHeight:'60%'}}>
   //Contains code for displaying a list item and each item has it's context menu that can be triggered from an icon click.
</div>
<div style={{maxHeight:'40%'}}></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @sahilatahar, I have updated the question with updated expected result.

Comment: @DeveshTiwari I think you have add a popup menu. if you have  `position: absolute`  then remove `overflow: hidden` if added and give `z-index: 10;` some higher value than your relative. If you are not using `position` property then add your CSS also in question.